# How to do a 3-tier using PHP

Tags: php

I have a requirement from a client for my PHP Web application to be 3-tier.  For example, I would have a web server on Apache in the DMZ, but it should NOT contain any DB connections.  It should connect to a Middle server that would host the business objects but be behind the firewall.  Then those objects connect to my SQL cluster on another server.

I have actually done this using .NET, but I am not sure how to setup my stack using PHP.  I suppose I could have my UI front tier call the middle tier using REST based web services if I create my middle tier as a second web server, but this seems overly complex.

The main reason for this is advanced security: we can not have any passwords on the DMZ first tier web server.  The second reason is scalability - to have multiple server on different tiers that can handle the requests.  The Last reason is for deployment - it is easier if I can take one set of servers offline for testing before putting them back in production.

Is there a open source project that shows how to do this?  The only example I can find is the web server hosting files from a shared drive on another machine (kind of how DotNetNuke pretends to be 3-tier), but that is NOT secure.

Note:  I HAVe looked in SO for this answer, and I do see a lot of similar questions, but have not found anyone that actually answered. This is NOT about a Data Access Layer (although I will use it) - my primary question is the design between UI and the Middle Tier.

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to use [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/).

On the first tier, simply have the front-end servers ([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/), [Lighttpd](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs:ModFastCGI), [NginX](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFcgiModule), etc) connect to FastCGI servers on the second tier.

The other option would be to reverse-proxy from the first-tier to the second-tier.  This is very similar to the first example except that the 2nd tier runs a web-server whereas with FastCGI it doesn't.

But the question you need to ask yourself is why.  You can achieve the same thing with 2 tiers and simply having a separate network for each tier (so the DMZ'd servers would have 2 network cards, one for each network).  The DB is still isolated from the world, but you don't have to worry about adding un-necessary complexity in the system...  Remember, the more pieces you add, the more than can fail...

Comment: Great answer and counter argument.  Lovely.

Comment: I know this is a more complex architecture, but it made sense when I did it in .NET :)

Comment: How would my PHP scripts on the web server talk to the FastCGI on the second tier?  And how would my PHP DAL object on the MiddleTier use FastCGI to call the DB?

Comment: @Ric:  Don't get me wrong, I'm not saying **not** to do it.  Just keep in mind that with complexity comes additional failure modes.  Now, if you determine that you need the additional complexity to gain the flexibility and scalability needed, then by all means do it.  Just consider what you're doing before jumping in head first (And make sure you can justify the choice).

Comment: @Ric: It wouldn't.  The webserver itself talks to PHP on the second tier via FastCGI.  PHP doesn't run at all on the first tier.  The entire PHP application space lives on the second tier.  The first tier has nothing but the public facing web-server(s).  Then PHP on the second-tier would connect to the DB directly (using the normal methods).

Comment: But then wouldn't that just make it really two tier?  The UI Logic should run on the WebServer and the Busines rules on the Middle tier.  When I did this in .NET, we would use a RPC over the Windows domain to call the COM+ middle tier.  I could do this in PHP using WebServices but was looking for a better way.

Comment: Well, you could split it up any way you want.  But keep in mind that more layers == slower.  So adding in an RPC layer, while it may open some doors, tends to slow things down for a production website.  If you're talking about an internal system (ordering, etc) then that's fine.  But for a normal website, that's a bit overkill (ok, more than a bit).  But you could use a RESTful API of some sort (SOAP, XMLRPC, JSONRPC, etc) to call from the first tier to the second, but I'm not sure what you're going to gain unless you're working with an edge-case that's quite specific...

Comment: Are there any Open source projects that show a true three tier?  I understand this _MAY_ be slower, but it is a client requirement, so I must implement something.

Comment: @Ric: The tools are available, but I'm not sure that you'll find much since outside of enterprise applications it's not very useful (in fact the negatives far outweigh the positives for all but the most paranoid).  Good luck implementing it, and release it as open source once you're done!  I've love to see what you finally wind up implementing...